# Electric generators

Tags: electromagnetism

When I rotate a coil in a magnetic field, there is a flux change. this induced an emf in the wire, generating electricity.

I saw a video of a windmill spinning really fast and breaking and got me thinking about an efficient way to fix this, without losing energy

Obviously the induced emf is in the opposite direction to the change in flux, so via amperes law this produces a magnetic field that opposes the change in flux, causing a torque in the opposite direction than the applied torque by the wind.

What things can I do to slow the speed of the windmill whilst also harnessing the same amount of energy

My thoughts would be to increase the current of the wire, for the same induced voltage (by keeping the shape the same) but changing the material to one of a high conductivity  thus inducing a higher current for the same emf, causing a stronger torque opposing my wind torque, thus slowing down the windmill and keeping the energy the same.

Or increasing the strength of the uniform magnetic field, causing the same effect.

Is this correct thinking? and if so, can someone show me the math of modelling such a process as it seems very very complicated e.g torque due to wind, then due to this torque find the equation of motion of my ring  then calculate the change in flux of this ring, then using faradays law calculate the induced emf  then using ohms law calculate the induced current  then calculate the resulting magnetic field using amperes law  then, find the  resistive torque experienced by this ring  due to the fact that it's a magnetic dipole in a magnetic field

if its bad enough  5, then there's the problem of the fact that the initial equation of motion is effected by this resistive torque

( would I need lagrangian mechanics to do this)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a possibility that the power from the wind may exceed what the electrical and mechanical system can handle, then the mill should have a speed governor that rotates the blades to reduce the angle between the blades and the wind.

Answer (score 0):

You can gain considerable insight using a very simple model of a generator: a plane coil of area $A$ and $N$ turns rotating at uniform angular velocity $\omega$ in a uniform magnetic field, $B$. Suppose that at time $t=0$, the normal to the coil is parallel to the uniform field. The magnetic flux linkage with the coil is therefore
$$N\Phi=BAN \cos \omega t$$

So the emf generated is
$$\mathscr E = -\frac{d}{dt}(N\Phi)=BAN\omega \sin \omega t$$
and if the circuit resistance is $R+r$, the current is
$$I=\frac{BAN}{R+r}\omega \sin \omega t$$
Therefore the magnetic torque on the coil is
$$G=BAIN \sin \omega t = \frac{B^2 A^2 N^2 \omega}{R+r} \sin^2 \omega t$$
So the mean torque over a cycle is
$$G= \frac{B^2 A^2 N^2 \omega}{2(R+r)} $$
For the coil to be rotating at a steady rate, this torque needs to be balanced by the applied torque.

The mean power input is therefore
$$P_{in}=G \omega = \frac{B^2 A^2 N^2 \omega^2}{2(R+r)} $$

It's easy to check that the mean value, $P_{out}$, of the electrical output power $\mathscr E I$, (some of which is wasted heating the coil (resistance r)) is the same, if we neglect frictional torque.

You can now see the factors governing the behaviour of the generator.